# Replace some letters at PUZZLE to find out a sentence

Tags: anagram, seasonal

```
 **zzle = Spout
 *u**le = Group
 *u**le = Make money
 ****le = A person who will love with her whole heart.
 p****e = A beautiful city in Central Europe
 p****e = A balerina loves to do this
 p****e = Slim and beautiful girl
 p****e = An epidemic disease
 p***le = Word of honor given or pledged
```

Use all the letters (represented by $*$) exactly once you find above to reveal what I want to say below :

$***************\;\;\;\;**\;\;\;\;******\;\;\;\;***\;\;\;\;*****$

**Hint**

> The sentence have something to do with moderator election

Comment: I could tell what the sentence was without the hint. :P

Comment: Better to solve the "puzzle" first, you can reverse it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**zzle = Spout

> NOZZLE

*u**le = Group

> BUNDLE

*u**le = Make money

> HUSTLE

****le = A person who will love with her whole heart.

> CAROLE  (I found this on Urban Dictionary; not sure where else it might come from?)

p****e = A beautiful city in Central Europe

> PRAGUE

p****e = A balerina loves to do this

> POINTE

p****e = Slim and beautiful girl

> PETITE

p****e = An epidemic disease

> PLAGUE

p***le = Word of honor given or pledged

> PAROLE

The message:

> CONGRATULATIONS TO GARETH AND RUBIO

Thank you!

Comment: Bah, was almost there, ninja'd. Oh well, have your first diamond upvote!